# Error c2146: syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
Vector2D mob::Seek(Vector2D target)
{
   Vector2D Velo;
   Vector2D Accn;
   Velo = (target – m_pos).unitVector();///here is where its pointing
   Accn = Velo-m_Velo;
   return Accn;
}
```

> Error 2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier
>   '–'   l:\bmb\bot.cpp  316 bmb

getting an error for this any ideas?

Comment: What is m_pos?  Does (target - m_pos) result in a Vector2D?

Comment: Vector2D m_Pos; and yes it does

Comment: Typo: `m_pos` should be `m_Pos` ?

Comment: no that wasnt it but makes me think if it didnt spot the typo

Comment: You changed it and recompilation produced exactly the same error ? Could you post declaration of `Vector2D` or provide a link to it?

Comment: yea i did change it, sec will do

Comment: nevermind friend pointed out there was something wrong with my - char i deleted it and retyped it and it started working thanks though hmjd and joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have somehow gotten an en dash where your minus operator should be.

Comment: Yes, I noticed your comment after I posted my answer.